# PHPMailer randomly stops sending mail after around 175 sent emails

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send a newsletter out from a list of emails in a database. The script queries the database, puts the data into an array with a while loop, and in the while loop creates and sends the email.

It works fine until after 150 or so emails are sent, then it randomly stops. As an example, email blast #1 failed after 161 sent emails, email blast #2 failed after 165 sent emails, and email blast #3 failed after 182 sent emails.

I have been researching and researching and cannot find the cause to this. Right now I send each email in it's on To: message, and don't send them using the BCC: route. Could it be settings on my server? If so, what should I be looking for?

I also have a little bit of debugging built in. The sql script at the end adds the email to the database, along with the specific time it was sent, so that I can tell exactly how many get sent, which email stops the process, and how long it takes.

The emails it stops on show no pattern (meaning they are different email providers) and it only takes around 10 - 12 minutes to send out that many. My script timeout on the server is way high than that so that isn't the cause.

My code is as follows:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "*server ip here*";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;                  // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "*user*";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "*pass*"; // SMTP password

while($select2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($select)) {
$email = $select2['email'];
$unid    = $select2['id'];
$unemail = $select2['email'];
$to = $email;
$from = "newsletter@site.com";
$new_date = date("n/j/y - g:i:s a");
$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message2 = "<html><body>";
$message2 .= $message;
$message2 .= "</body></html>";

$mail->From = "newsletter@site.com";
$mail->FromName = "Newsletter";
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->AddReplyTo("newsletter@site.com", "Website.com");

$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message2;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    die("mail() Failed to send email to $to.");
    echo "<br><br>Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
} else {
    $make_sent_query = "INSERT INTO emailssent (email_signup_id, email, datesent) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $params_sent = array($unid, $to, $new_date);
    $add_to_sent = sqlsrv_query($conn, $make_sent_query, $params_sent);
    if($add_to_sent) {
        echo "Message sent for email $to<br>";
    } else {
        die("Mail sent, but failed to insert into Sent Emails database.");
    }
}

$mail->ClearAddresses();  //clear addresses for next loop
}
```

Comment: Are you hitting a PHP or Web Server timeout?

Comment: As far as I know, neither. It just randomly is stopping. I've set the script execution time to like an hour, and it stops after 15~ mins.

Comment: Does it echo any of your messages within the loop?

Comment: It echos when a message is sent and if there are errors. No particular error seems to make it completely stop running though. I am going to try today with a sleep() command and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be being caused by your local mail server? If you're sending out 150 emails in a short space of time, it might be assuming that it's spamming, and stop once you reach a certain amount.

You could try slowing it down with a sleep() after sending each mail? Just a second or two should be enough if that is the cause....

Is there a reason why you want to avoid using BCC? You can send email to multiple recipients and reduce the number of emails you're sending to a fraction of what you're sending now, though it is at the cost of not being able to individualise each email.

Comment: I have no problem trying BCC, I just feel like it would look more spammy to do that. I know adding the SPF records will help with that, although I'm still a little iffy about trying it. 

I also haven't tried the sleep command. I think I will do that and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's timeout problem. And crontab can solve your problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron . You can write script to send your emails and set your crontab to run this script every minutes. Then you have never had a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

One of the potential reasons can be PHP timing out the script. Every script gets to run for a limited amount of time. If your script takes more time than that then PHP will simply kill the script. Typically that should cause an error being reported in the error logs. Check your apache error log messages - they might contain a hint.

Answer (score 0):

it is caused by the max_execution_time in XAMPP,
so, the script of sending emails will stop when the script is running above the max_execution_time.
the default max_execution_time  is 120seconds.
sending many emails takes much times.

you can change it by adding this script

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

put it before your email blasting script section, it tells the php to set it to unlimited max_execution_time.